# Оптимизация хранения анимаций LibGdx

Tags: java, анимация, libgdx

Работаю с LibGdx.

Интересует следующий вопрос: как можно оптимизировать хранение большого количества изображений для анимаций?

Дело в том, что я не могу постоянно подгружать их через вспомогательный `findRegions()` класса `TextureAtlas`, этот метод далеко не быстрый. При этом, я должен обращатся к конкретной анимации каждый кадр для взятия и отрисовки текущего кадра. Чтобы как-нибудь сохранять анимации, использовал `HashMap<NameOfAnimation, Animation>`.

Для точности приведу числа: для каждого из 4 неодинаковых персонажей требуется сохранить 3552 кадра анимаций (все анимации имеют 8 сторон: бег, бой, смерть, не занят). Как вы понимаете, это очень затратно. Это не только плохо влияет на производительность, но иногда является причиной вылетания приложения из-за ограниченного объема оперативной памяти на телефоне. Я не вижу пути, как я могу обойти данную проблему.

Comment: Могут ли все 4 персонажа находиться одновременно на экране? Если нет, то спрайты нужно распихать по разным текстурам. На экране кроме персонажей нет других объектов? Может память переполняется по другой причине (хотя 3552 кадра анимации это очень много). Сколько весят текстуры с анимацией и сколько памяти в телефоне?

Comment: @MasterFlomaster

Все 4 персонажа могут находиться одновременно на экране. На нем, кроме персонажей, есть другие объекты, но их не так много. Память переполняется из-за анимаций, т.к. при подзагрузке только двух видов из четырех (бег, не занят, например), проседания исчезают, и приложение идет плавно даже при увеличении количества персонажей.
Атлас, на котором расположены все анимации, весит 1,74 Мб. RAM на телефоне 2 Гб. 
Остается еще добавить, что, при загрузке всех анимаций и всех персонажей, на компьютере приложение не подвисает и идет плавно.

Comment: В таком случае остается 2 пути: либо уменьшить количество анимаций, либо писать свой TextureAtlas, для более оптимального хранения данных

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, попробую.